# Bootstrap Modal Opens Multiple Modals, Should Open Only One at a Time

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a page that has about 5 - 6 links that open their unique modal windows. However if I click on any link that should fire a modal window, that link opens ALL the modal windows on that page.

How can I get only the relevant modal window to open?

Code and Screenshot below.

Links Firing the Modal

HTML

```
<a class="btn-simple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#more-locations">
     More locations<i class="arrow right"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn-simple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-unique-id">
     Let's Go<i class="arrow right"></i>
</a>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal  custom-modal" id="modal-unique-id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-unique-id">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-unique-id">Get a bundled home & Auto Quote</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;border:none;min-height:500px;height:auto;"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal More Locations -->
<div class="modal  custom-modal" id="more-locations" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="more-locations">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="more-locations">More Locations</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="lo-licenced-states">
                    Content for second modal
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: As a side note, the `ID` must be unique in the page but you have declared the same `ID` twice for each of the modals you have.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="modal-trigger" data-modal="1">Modal 1</a>
<a href="#" class="modal-trigger" data-modal="2">Modal 2</a>
<div class="modal" style="display: none;" id="1">hi i am modal 1</div>
<div class="modal" style="display: none;" id="2"> hi i am modal 2</div>
```

Js

```
$(".modal-trigger").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  dataModal = $(this).attr("data-modal");
  $("#" + dataModal).css({"display":"block"});
       
});
```

Or

```
$(".btn-simple").on("click", function(){
  $($(this).data("target")).modal("show");
});
```

Make sure modal id is same as data-target.

```js
$(".modal-trigger").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  dataModal = $(this).attr("data-modal");
  $("#" + dataModal).css({"display":"block"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="modal-trigger" data-modal="1">Modal 1</a>
<a href="#" class="modal-trigger" data-modal="2">Modal 2</a>
<div class="modal" style="display: none;" id="1"> hi i am modal 1</div>
<div class="modal" style="display: none;" id="2"> hi i am modal 2</div>
```

Comment: That does not work for me. I copied the scripts and HTML and pasted. Not sure why.

Comment: it should work, Open console tells me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but make sure to load Bootstrap css, then jquery then load the Bootstrap javascript. I added divs around your buttons to make them easier to tell apart. The data-target and modal id match, and the ids are unique.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<a class="btn-simple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#more-locations">
     More locations<i class="arrow right"></i>
</a>
</div>

<div>
<a class="btn-simple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-unique-id">
     Let's Go<i class="arrow right"></i>
</a>
</div>
<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal  custom-modal" id="modal-unique-id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-unique-id">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-unique-id">Get a bundled home & Auto Quote</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;border:none;min-height:500px;height:auto;"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal More Locations -->
<div class="modal  custom-modal" id="more-locations" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="more-locations">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="more-locations">More Locations</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="lo-licenced-states">
                    Content for second modal
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```